# Linking with GCC fails after switching boost version from 1.52 to 1.53

Tags: gcc, boost, linker, boost-thread

After upgrading the boost libraries form version 1.52 to 1.53 I get the following linker error when building with GCC under Linux. The same application builds fine under Windows with VC++10 and boost 1.53.

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L"/home/robert/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib" -L/usr/lib -o "MyApp"  ./myObjectFile.o -lboost_log_setup-mt-s -lboost_log-mt-s -lboost_thread-mt-s -lboost_system-mt-s -lboost_regex-mt-s -lcryptopp -lboost_date_time-mt-s -lpthread -ldl -lboost_filesystem-mt-s
/home/robert/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-s.a(thread.o): In function `boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_for(timespec const&)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0xc10): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/home/robert/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-s.a(thread.o): In function `boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_until(timespec const&)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0x1425): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
thread.cpp:(.text+0x14cd): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
thread.cpp:(.text+0x159c): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
thread.cpp:(.text+0x1684): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/home/robert/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-s.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.text+0x176e): more undefined references to `clock_gettime' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I built the boost libraries like this:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc
./b2 --layout=tagged variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static cxxflags=-std=c++0x
```

My GCC version is 4.7.2

Comment: Shouldn't this be fixed in boost? If boost needst lrt, it's his job to link against it, not user's?

Comment: On what platform are you building?

Comment: That was on Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically says that `clock_gettime` function is not found by the linker. This function is in `rt` library, so add `-lrt` to the linker command line.

Comment: In case someone struggles with this as-well using Codeblocks, there you just have to add -rt (NOT -lrt) to the top of "Other linker options".

Comment: Actually the above is a false statement, -lrt or -rt doesn't work for me somehow. :-(